# linkedin logout issue

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I am logged into my application with linkedin connect, but on logout i logs out of the application and not linkedin. I want user to log out of both linkedin and my application

Facebook have provide an option for the same as below

http://m.facebook.com/logout.php?confirm=1&next={domain url}

IF any one know the same thing with linkedin, It will help me a lot.

Thanks in advance

Comment: looking at the LinkedIn developer forum it Looks like this is a known issue. Check this blog post about [Token Expiration](http://blog.linkedin.com/2010/04/29/linkedin-platform-oauth/) and see if it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I have been in trouble for this log out from linkedin for quite sometime but finally found a way out. I have placed my log out link code here:

```
<a onclick='IN.User.logout(
function redirect()
{
window.location = "logout.php";
}
);'
href="javascript:void(0)">
Log Me Out
</a>
```

onClick of the logout button, I have called "IN.User.logout" and on its callback, I have given control to the function which redirects to log out script (logout.php in this case) where I log the user out of my system.

I think this should help most of people here.

Comment: I think you're missing details in the javascript required to run this.

Comment: This function works but when i leave my site ideal for some time, it doesn't work.